# Coldfusion CFSEARCH: indexing SQL data with Solr

Tags: coldfusion, solr, indexing, cfsearch

I read the *Indexing SQL data* chapter of the "Web Application Construction Kit", by Ben Forta.

Passing a query object to the CFINDEX tag is great for building an index from scratch setting my table's "productName" as the document title, "productDescription" as the body and so on.

Anyway, my query produces a result set like this:

```
productName    |    attributeType    |    attributeValue

prod1          |    color            |    green
prod1          |    gender           |    man
prod2          |    color            |    blue
prod2          |    gender           |    woman
prod3          |    color            |    green
prod3          |    gender           |    unisex
```

... and so on.

How do I have to index / search with in order to search "*I',m looking for a green watch, I am a man*" and be sure to find the "prod1" first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using categories - you have to create a collection which supports categories (it brings a bit of overhead) and provide "category" attribute while indexing db records. Then while searching you can limit your scope to the categories of interest. BTW, multiple categories could be applied to the single item if you need to do so.